# Number of solutions of nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Find the number of *unique* solutions of the following nonlinear ODE $$y' = \frac{10}{3} x y^\frac25, \qquad y(0)=-1$$

---

**My attempt**

Via the method of separation of variables, I got

$$y = \left( x^2 - 1 \right)^\frac53$$

Via *uniqueness theorem*, the above solution is unique in $(-1,1)$. By branching it off at the end points of this interval with $y=0$, I could construct four distinct solutions. Can we somehow construct more solutions, specifically *infinitely many solutions* to this ODE?

Comment: You cannot use separation of variables if the equation is not a first-order differential equation. This equation is a second order differential equation.

Comment: The term "number of unique solutions" is unclear: if it has more than one solution, each of the solution is not an unique solution.

Comment: I am looking for the *distinct* solutions that can be constructed in the whole of $R$ , (even though all of them must overlap in $ (-1,1)$ as guaranteed by Uniqueness theorem)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use separation of variables to solve a second-order differential equation. As Moo noted in the comments to your post, you can differentiate your function twice, and verify that it does not satisfy the equation. Also, there is no uniqueness theorem that can apply to your equation, because you only provided one boundary condition, not two.

Let $z=y^{\frac15},$ hence $$y''(x)=(z^5)''(x)=\frac{10}3xz(x)^2=(5z^4z')'(x)=20z^3(x)z'(x)^2+5z(x)^4z''(x),$$ which is equivalent to $$5z(x)^2\left[z(x)^2z''(x)+4z(x)^3z'(x)^2-\frac23x\right]=0,$$ implying $z(x)=0$ or $$z(x)^2z''(x)+4z(x)^3z'(x)^2-\frac23x=0.$$ I do not believe this latter equation can be solved analytically.

---

Given the way you phrased the problem, and given how you went about mistakenly solving it, I assume you actually meant to write the differential equation as $$y'(x)=\frac{10}3xy(x)^{\frac25},$$ instead. Then having only one boundary condition is justified in this situation. This can be solved with separation of variables. Hence $y(x)=0$ or $$y(x)^{-\frac25}y'(x)=\frac{10}3x\implies\left[\frac53y^{\frac35}\right]'(x)=\left(\frac53x^2\right)'\implies\left[y^{\frac35}\right]'(x)=\left(x^2\right)'.$$ By Riemann integrating, you obtain $$y(t)^{\frac35}-y(0)^{\frac35}=t^2.$$ So in fact, you do obtain $y(t)=(t^2-1)^{\frac53},$ and this is the only solution everywhere in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Apologies for the typo, rectified now.  Please have a look at Example 2.3.7 here https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Elementary_Differential_Equations_with_Boundary_Value_Problems_(Trench)/02%3A_First_Order_Equations/2.03%3A_Existence_and_Uniqueness_of_Solutions_of_Nonlinear_Equations

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha Thank you for clarifying. I took a look at the source you linked, and according to the theorem stated in the source, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere for $x\in(a,b),$ then the solution exists and is unique in that interval. Now, $f$ is actually continuous everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ so I am confused as to why you are limiting yourself to the interval $x\in(-1,1).$ The solution is unique everywhere. In fact, for this special case, the uniqueness theorem is not actually needed to establish that: you can merely establish it by solving the function as I did.